# Is there anyone can help me for the pulsar perf?

Tags: java, pulsar

I use the pulsar perf to test the service by the command: pulsar-perf produce topic1 -n 1 -t 10 -r 1000000, but the log shows that the Throughtput Produced just below 10000, i need to test the service by higher message rate, how can i do ?

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information. Also see [ask].

Comment: ok, i have edited, do you know why the rate of msg is just below 100000 even if i use the -r 1000000 ?

Comment: The message rate will be limited by the capabilities of the hardware on which you run `pulsar-perf`.

Comment: the pulsar perf will set the rate according to hardware? so which one , the memory or cpu or others ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure you are using the command correctly, you can use a extra low limit, for instance 100 and then 1000.

If you see the expected behavior, and it hits the ceiling at exactly 10000, it is likely a software limit.

If you see it around 10000 it is likely a hardware limit. Check which resource of your hardware is utilized fully (cpu, disk, memory, network) and try it on a box with more resources.